# Django UserProfile signals create user, first_name, last_name

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I'm creating a UserProfile using the User data, I want to pass to first_name and last_name as well.

Here is my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

def post_save_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(post_save_user, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I've tried this using `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, first_name=instance.first_name, last_name=instance.last_name)` , it's creating the profile but it's not adding the first_name and last_name.

Question: How can I add first_name and last_name to profile using the user data?

Comment: What's the point of putting first_name and last_name in the profile? Those are already available in the user model.

Comment: hm.. yea you're right, i was just curious